# Is it possible for the spouse of an EU citizen to work in Ireland while the residence permit application is pending?

Tags: residency, ireland, eu-spouses

I am a spouse of an EU citizen and we are thinking of going to Ireland.  I know if I want to stay there more than three months I have to get the Residence Card For a qualifying family member of a Union citizen, so my questions are the following:

1. In real life how long aprox does it take to be given. In the page said maximum 6 months,
2. Do they give a certificate that validates that you are waiting for the residency? If that is the case can yu work with that?.

My real concern is that the residency can take up to six month for the response and that the appliant has to wait for that to be able to work. Is that the case or there are other options?

Comment: They are required by the directive to give you a receipt indicating that you've applied for the permit.  I don't know whether that allows you to work.

Comment: relatives of EU citizens should be able to start working at the same time as their EU citizen relatives without any kind of work permit: http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=463 proving this to your prospective employer might not be easy though, as they might require your residence card (which should not be needed)